# How do I make the players array available outside the d3 function

Tags: javascript, arrays, xml, d3.js

I am working on visualizing baseball statistics. I am using an xml file containing the stats and am trying to use d3 to visualize them, but i want to have an array conaining all the stats in javascript. i can get the information i'm looking for into an array inside the function, but then outside the function the array is undefined.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
   <title>D3.xml Example</title>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="http://mbostock.github.com/d3/d3.v2.js"></script>
   <style type="text/css">
.chart div {
   font: 10px sans-serif;
   background-color: steelblue;
   text-align: right;
   padding: 3px;
   margin: 1px;
   color: white;
   display:inline-block;
   width:30px;
 }
 .howard {
   background-color: red;
 }
    </style
</head>
<body>
<div id="chart" class="chart">

</div>
<script>
d3.xml("updatedphillies.xml", "application/xml", function(xml) {
  d3.select("#chart")
    .selectAll("div")
    .data(xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("doubles"))
    .enter().append("div")
      .style("height", function(d) { return d.textContent * 1 + 10 + "px"; })
      .text(function(d) { return d.textContent; });
  console.log(xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("player"));
});



</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: d3.xml is an asynchronous call. The function is a callback function that runs after the console.log runs, so even if you set a global variable inside it, it won't get set before console.log picks is up. I think any array you define to store the xml will need to be within the function's execution stack.

Comment: can i create the array of xml in javascript first, then use d3 to create the visualization something like this:

var array = [xml data i want]

d3 function to code underneath this with a reference to the array above.

Comment: Yes, that should work - the d3 functions you have inside the d3.xml callback aren't asynchronous.

Comment: how would i even do that? i tried to do:

var players = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("players"); but it says that xml is not defined.